# Is it possible to obtain %0.05 duty cycle at 1hz in arduino?(a 500us square pulse at 1 sec period)

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, analogwrite

I have a system which requires me to obtain different duty cycles at different frequencies. But using the analogWrite() does not allow me to obtain a value lower than 1/255 duty cycle. I need to obtain lower duty cycle values for 1Hz

Comment: Is it OK if, at 1 Hz, you are restricted to pulse widths which are multiples of 16 µs? E.g. you would have 496 µs instead of 500. If so, you can configure Timer 1 to generate the PWM signal on pins 9 or 10. A signal generated this way would have more consistent timing than a similar signal generated by software (e.g. using `micros()`).

Comment: @EdgarBonet - could you explain where are you getting the 16us from?  Several prescalar and count value possibilities will yield 500us, but I'm not immediately thinking of any that yield your numbers.

Comment: Prescaler = 256 → resolution = 16 us and maximum period = 1.048576 s.

Comment: Ok, the maximum interval is a point - but that doesn't have to come from the same timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding from my comment. This is an attempt to generate that signal with Timer 1. <s>No time to test it now...</s> **Edit**: tested, works as advertised.

```
/*
 * Configure Timer 1 to generate a slow, low duty cycle PWM signal.
 * Output pin = digital 9 = PB1 = OC1A.
 */

const float PWM_PERIOD  = 1.0;     // 1 s
const float PULSE_WIDTH = 500e-6;  // 500 us

/*
 * With a 16 MHz clock and this prescaler, the resolution is 16 us and
 * the maximum period is 1.048576 s.
 */
const uint16_t TIMER_PRESCALER = 256;
const float F_TIMER = F_CPU / TIMER_PRESCALER;

void setup()
{
    // Configure Timer 1.
    DDRB  |= _BV(PB1);    // set PB1 = OC1A as output
    ICR1   = round(PWM_PERIOD * F_TIMER) - 1;
    OCR1A  = round(PULSE_WIDTH * F_TIMER) - 1;
    TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1)  // non-inverting PWM on OC1A
           | _BV(WGM11);  // fast PWM mode, TOP = ICR1
    TCCR1B = _BV(WGM12)   // ditto
           | _BV(WGM13)   // ditto
           | _BV(CS12);   // clock at F_CPU/256 = 62.5 kHz
}

void loop() {}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, It works great but I would like to get the same thing for 2 different pins and I have no idea about registers. Can you tell me how can I make this code applicable for pin 10 and pin 8?

Comment: @allta: You can't. Hardware-based PWM only works on pins `OCnA` and `OCnB`, where _n_ = 0, 1, or 2 is the index of the timer you use. The small duty cycle you want can only be achieved with a 16-bit timer, and you have only one such timer on the Uno: Timer 1. Thus you can only use pins 9 (OC1A) and 10 (OC1B). C.f. the [Arduino Uno pinout](http://www.pighixxx.com/test/portfolio-items/uno/?portfolioID=314). See also the tutorial [Timers and counters](http://www.gammon.com.au/timers) by Nick Gammon.

Comment: Thank you again
It's ok we can use the pin10 we won't use the pin 9 and 10 simultaneously. Will changing OC1A with OC1B would work for pin 10? How can I modify this code for pin 10?

Comment: @allta: Yes. `OCR1B` controls pin 10 in the same way as `OCR1A` controls pin 9.

Comment: void setup()
{
    // Configure Timer 1.
    DDRB  |= _BV(PB2);    // set PB1 = OC1A as output
    ICR1   = round(PWM_PERIOD * F_TIMER) - 1;
    OCR1B  = round(PULSE_WIDTH * F_TIMER) - 1;
    TCCR1A = _BV(COM1B1)  // non-inverting PWM on OC1B
           | _BV(WGM11);  // fast PWM mode, TOP = ICR1
    TCCR1B = _BV(WGM12)   // ditto
           | _BV(WGM13)   // ditto
           | _BV(CS12);   // clock at F_CPU/256 = 62.5 kHz
}
didn't work I don't get how can I modify the last part correctly

Comment: @allta: Your modified `setup()` works for me: I get the PWM signal on pin 10.

Comment: Now it worked for me too, thank you again

Answer (score 2):

Sure - if you program it to.

1. Turn on an output.
2. Wait for 500µs less the amount of time it took to turn on the output
3. Turn off the output
4. Wait for 0.9995 seconds minus the amount of time it took to turn off the output
5. Go to 1.

You would probably find using the `micros()` function easiest to get the timing right - in exactly the same way as the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example in the IDE.

Also [direct port manipulation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation) may be of benefit to make things as fast as possible.

Comment: You must also account for the time spent outside `loop`. There is some conditional code executed out there (plus calls, returns and interrupts), so execution time is variable from pass to pass. That's the problem with `delay`: you don't know how much time will pass before the next execution of `loop`. Better use `micros`.

Comment: Yes, hence my instruction to use micros.

Comment: Sorry. I was aware of your original `micro` recomendation. I was just adding reasons for it. I didn't express myself correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Two easy way to do it.

1. 0,05 percent is 1:2000. So modify timer settings to produce a pen of the desired frequency and duty cycle.
2. Use timer interrupt: either the overflow or compare match interrupt. In the first case, load the timer with -duty cycle and -(period - duty) to produce a wave form of duty cycle / period.

The same can be done using compare match as well: just advance the match point alternately.

edit: to show how it can be done with compare match, here is what I have:

```
#define PR_PWM          (F_CPU / 256 / 10)      //period for the pwm waveform
#define PR_ON           (PR_PWM * 25 / 100)         //prescaler at 256:1, 25% duty cycle
#define PR_OFF          (PR_PWM - PR_ON)            //pin off period, to achieve 1Hz
//end hardware configuration

//global defines

//global variables

//timer1 ch a compare match isr
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
    static char pr_index=0;     //0->PR_ON, 1->PR_OFF

    //clear the flag  -  done automatically
    //advance to the next match point
    if ((pr_index++ & 0x01) == 0) {
        OCR1A += PR_ON;
        IO_SET(PWM_PORT, PWM);  //set the pin on
    } else {
        OCR1A += PR_OFF;
        IO_CLR(PWM_PORT, PWM);  //clear the pin
    }

}
```

for this demo, we tried to generate a 25% duty cycle pwm with a period of 100ms. Here is the output of that code.

[image]

The follow changes the duty cycle to 0.05%:

```
#define PR_ON           (PR_PWM * 0.05 / 100)           //prescaler at 256:1, 0.05% duty cycle
```

and the corresponding output is:

[image]

Now, there are other ways to do it, for example, with higher resolution, or more precision, ..., but at the cost of more coding.

But the basic concept is the same.

hope it helps.

edit2: for those brave souls, the isr can be simplified to:

```
OCR1A += (pr_index++&0x01)?PR_OFF:PR_ON;  //advance the match point
IO_FLP(PWM_PORT, PWM);  //flip the pwm pin
```

Comment: A pen? It must be a typo

Comment: @LookAlterno Unless he means to draw the waveform on a piece of paper...?!